# Exception when resolving generically typed concrete class from non-generic interface

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

#### The Context

I have a non-generic interface, `IInputEventProvider` that is implemented by a concrete class, `InputEventProvider<TState, TInputEvent>`.

In my installer, I register the concrete type four times with different generic type parameters like so:

```
.Register(
    Component.For<IInputEventProvider>()
        .ImplementedBy<InputEventProvider<KeyboardState, KeyboardEvent>>(),
    Component.For<IInputEventProvider>()
        .ImplementedBy<InputEventProvider<MouseState, MouseButtonEvent>>(),
    Component.For<IInputEventProvider>()
        .ImplementedBy<InputEventProvider<MouseState, MouseMoveEvent>>(),
    Component.For<IInputEventProvider>()
        .ImplementedBy<InputEventProvider<MouseState, ScrollWheelEvent>>()
)
```

I also do a convention-based registration of all the classes in my assembly against their interfaces:

```
.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<MainClass>()
        .Pick()
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
)
```

Finally in one of my classes I take a dependency on `IEnumerable<IInputEventProvider>`, which should return my four registered type instances.

#### The Issue

When resolving at my composition root, I get the following exception:

> Requested type Exuinoq.Core.Input.IInputEventProvider has 0 generic
>   parameter(s), whereas component implementation type
>   Exuinoq.Core.Input.InputEventProvider`2[TState,TInputEvent] requires
>   2.

This is because the convention-based registration in the installer has picked up the generic concrete class and registered it as a generic type, which then cannot be resolved.

#### The Question

**What is the best way to avoid this and prevent it happening to other classes in the future?** The exception gives the following advice:

> You can instruct Windsor which types it should use to close this
>   generic component by supplying an implementation of
>   IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy.

However, I think this only applies to when you wish to register a *single* type, not four different ones. I could be wrong though!

For the time being I have used this workaround but it is hardly sustainable:

```
.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<MyClass>()
        .Where(t => !typeof(IInputEventProvider).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
)
```

Comment: the exception is not about your four explicitly registered components. you other registration most likely picks up the class again as open generic. you can verify it by looking at all services diagnostic

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by "This is because the convention-based registration in the installer has picked up the generic concrete class and registered it as a generic type, which then cannot be resolved". I know the cause, I want to know the solution :)

Comment: solution is simple, instead of `.Pick()` use `.Where(somethingToFilterUnwantedTypesOut)`

Comment: That's a bit like the classic description of "How to fly to the moon in 3 easy steps"... I'm aware of the `.Where()` operator (clearly - I mention it in my question). What I would like to know is the best implementation of `somethingToFilterUnwantedTypesOut` or an equivalent to prevent this happening.

Comment: it depends what exactly you want to prevent from happening. This particular type? Any generic type? The one you've got in your updated answer will get the job done in this scenario. It's perfectly fine if you only have this one type as an exception.

Comment: That doesn't seem very extensinble. What if I choose to add another class/interface pair like this? And then another? I think ideally there would be an alternative to `.WithServiceAllInterfaces()` where it will only register interfaces that it is able to resolve

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to mark all such concrete classes with an attribute such as `[RegisterWith(Type t, Type t2)]` - however it's advisable to keep container-related code away from everything else so it's something I'd like to avoid if possible. I do prefer this solution over hardcoding the undesirable types in the container though - it's more convention than configuration.